# Is there a way to avoid calling constructor and destructor for perfect forwarding to a function?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, c++17, perfect-forwarding

I am trying to pass literal to a perfect forwarding setter, but this results in object construction, movement and destruction instead. I am looking for a more efficient way to do this.

```
struct TStruct {
    TStruct(int va) : a(va) {
        std::cout << "- TStruct(" << va << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    TStruct(const TStruct& other) :
        a(other.a)
    {
        std::cout << "- TStruct(const TStruct& )" << std::endl;
    }
    TStruct(TStruct&& other) :
        a(std::exchange(other.a, 0))
    {
        std::cout << "- TStruct(const TStruct&&)" << std::endl;
    }
    TStruct& operator=(const TStruct& rhs) {
        std::cout << "- TStruct operator= const& " << std::endl;
        // check for self-assignment
        if(&rhs == this) return *this;
        a = rhs.a;
        return *this;
    }
    TStruct& operator=(TStruct&& rhs) {
        std::cout << "- TStruct operator=&&" << std::endl;
        // check for self-assignment
        if(&rhs == this) return *this;
        a = std::exchange(rhs.a, 0);
        return *this;
    }
    ~TStruct() {
        std::cout << "~ TStruct() destructor with " << a << std::endl;
    }
    int a = 1;
};

struct TPerfectForward {
    template<class T>
    TPerfectForward(T&& tsv) : ts(std::forward<T>(tsv)) {}

    template<class T>
    void set(T&& tsv) { ts = std::forward<T>(tsv); }

    TStruct ts;
};

std::cout << "TPerfectForward (5)" << std::endl;
TPerfectForward pf(5);

std::cout << "TPerfectForward set(4)" << std::endl;
pf.set(4);
```

This gives following results with gcc 7.4.0 on Ubuntu:

```
TPerfectForward (5);
- TStruct(5)
TPerfectForward set(4)
- TStruct(4)
- TStruct operator=&&
~ TStruct() destructor with 0
```

I would like these results better:

```
TPerfectForward (5)
- TStruct(5)
TPerfectForward set(4)
- TStruct(4)
```

Is there a way to avoid calling move operator and destructor when perfect forwarding to a function?

Comment: The perfect forwarding did work. You made `set` assign the parameter to `ts`, and that's exactly what happened (the assignment operator got called).

Comment: That's all correct: Your `operator=` accepts a reference to a struct, thus a temporary struct needs to be created so that there is something the reference can refer to. If you want to avoid that temporary, you need an `operator=` accepting an `int`.

Comment: `pf.set(4)` must replace an existing value of `pf.ts` with a new value. Then what makes you expect it shouldn't call any form of assignment operator?

Comment: If you want to check if perfect forwarding really works, try `pf.set(TStruct(5));` – now you have your temporary created already as parameter to `set` and you should still get the same output. If PF fails, then you'll see two structs created.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry and did not state my question correctly. Now I fixed that. I see that it is a normal behaviour, because constructor cannot be called multiple times for already existing object. Yet, is there a better way to write a setter to avoid calling constructor, move constructor and destructor? Is there a better way than overloading an assignment operator in TStruct for int?

Comment: You can convert an `int` to a `TStruct` via constructor, but you cannot assign and `int`. What you want is an `operator=(int)`.